# ECONNREFUSED at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect NodeJS

Tags: node.js, docker, rabbitmq

i created a nodejs app which should use a URI to connect to rabbitmq. both are containerized with docker and are created by a docker-compose file. after running of "docker-compose up" the nodejs app returns an error:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED X.X.X:X:5672
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1133:16) {
errno: -111,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '172.26.0.4',
port: 5672
}
```

when starting the api-server locally (not as a container-> as an node application), the connection to the containerized rabbitmq server estabilish without any problems.

my rabbitmq.conf file looks like:

```
default_vhost = /
default_user = guest
default_pass = guest
default_user_tags.administrator = true
default_permissions.configure = .*
default_permissions.read = .*
default_permissions.write = .*
loopback_users = none
listeners.tcp.default = 5672
management.listener.port = 15672
management.listener.ssl = false
management.load_definitions = /etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json
```

URI for connecting:

```
{  
    "mongoURI":"mongodb://mongo:27017",     
    "amqpURI": "amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672"
    }
```

as you can see, the hostname is equal to the one, which is within the docker-compose file

finally the docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  react-app:
    image: react-app
    stdin_open: true
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - mern-app
  api-server:
    image: api-server
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    networks:
      - mern-app
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - rabbitmq
  process-schedular:
    image: process-schedular
    ports:
      - "5005:5005"
    networks:
      - mern-app
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - rabbitmq
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.6.19-xenial
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - mern-app
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    hostname: rabbitmq
    volumes:
      - ./server/amqp/docker/enabled_plugins:/etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins
      - ./server/amqp/docker/definitions.json:/etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json
      - ./server/amqp/docker/rabbitmq.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    networks:
      - mern-app
networks:
  mern-app:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  mongo-data:
    driver: local
```